# How to call an object's methods and use varialbles

Tags: javascript

I have a small piece of code here, which is a model of some situation I am stuck with. For me as a PHP programmer this is so easy to do in PHP, but I never know how to do this in JS. Maybe someone can help.

```
var counterObj = {

items: [1,4,7],

total: 0,

run: function() {

    $.each(this.items, function(i, item){
        // Call my own method
        this.add(item);
    })
    .promise()
    .done(function(){

        // doubt it will log 12
        console.log(this.total);
    });
},

add: function(item){
    this.total = this.total + item;
}
};

counterObj.run();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EH9qK/

Comment: promose......... I'll read the docs again

Comment: `.promose()` is that a new method or something

Comment: No i fixed that, spelling mistake. Hope you were just trying to be funny.

Comment: @SaifBechan - The problem in your code is that `this` is referring to the number in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
run: function() {
    $.each(this.items, function(i, item){
        this.add(item);
    })
    .promise()
    .done(function(){
        console.log(this.total);
    });
}
```

`this` inside `$.each` is referring to the number in your array (blame jQuery for that.) Instead, you should do this:

```
run: function() {
    var _this = this;
    $.each(this.items, function(){
        _this.add(this);  //so many "this"
    });
    console.log(this.total);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/EH9qK/4/

By the way, `.promise` and `.done` only exist in jQuery objects. `$.each` returns the original array.

---

`this` in JavaScript is [a really confusing keyword](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html). It can also be changed with `.apply`, which is what jQuery has done in its methods:

> The value can also be accessed through the `this` keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value.
>   <sub>From [jQuery's docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)</sub>

But even if jQuery isn't modifying `this`, it would still be referring to the wrong object (`window`).

Oh yea, `1 + 4 + 7` is `12`, not `13`. :)

Comment: I would not recommend using the variable 'self' since it points to the 'window' object by default in browsers.'that' or '_this' would be much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Each function you declare creates another scope. All you have to do is bind the functions to the counterObject by calling the bind 'method'. I don't understand the use of 'promise' but I tried to make as little changes as I can in your code so my changes will be clear.

```
var counterObj = {

    items: [1,4,7],

    total: 0,

    run: function() {

        $.each(this.items, function(i, item){
            // Call my own method
            this.add(item);
        }.bind(this))
        .promise()
        .done(function(){

            // doubt it will log 13
            console.log(this.total);
        }.bind(this));
    },

    add: function(item){
        this.total = this.total + item;
    }
};

counterObj.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the functions that are supposed to be public from your scope, otherwise they are considered private.

For your example:

```
var counterObject = {
    ...
    return {
        run: run
    };
};
```